# How to detect the carrier for a phone number in India?

Tags: web-services, api

This could be a locale specific question. I am trying to find out the network operator  for a given phone number. I have seen a similar service on www.bmobile.in but unable to find any documentation w.r.t APIs etc.  <del>It seems to work even with numbers who have switched operators while retaining the number.</del> It shows the original operator the number was registered with.

Comment: Read [**this thread**](http://forum.groovypost.com/hardware-software/how-to-identify-mobile-carrier-from-cell-number-t95597.html). You would find similar threads just googling

Comment: I have googled quite a bit and found responses regarding getting the network name on the device itself. However I am interested in building something more dynamic which allows you to detect (say, your friend's) network from his phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Hy! You can try using this web-app:
http://www.fonefinder.net/

Comment: I am trying to build an application around it. so this does not serve my purpose.